# AirPlay via AppleTV stutters on retina MacBook Pro but not iPhone 4

Tags: macos, audio, network, macbook-pro, airplay

I recently got a retina Macbook Pro and I am loving it except for one thing. When I go to System Preferences > Sound > Output and select AirPlay while playing audio, the sound will often just stop or stutter for a period of time from less than a second to 6 or 7 seconds. The music is not just pausing because I can see on iTunes, Spotify, or YouTube that the audio continues to play. Yet on my iPhone 4 when using AirPlay, it never stutters or pauses.

What gives?

I tried switching the wireless channel on my router without luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I saw the chatter over on the official Apple forums last week and there has been some success on Retina MBP owners with the workaround [here](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/4149309?start=120&tstart=0) (and listed below)

Go to System Preferences -> Energy Saver -> Uncheck 'Automatic Graphics Switching'

This will of course switch 100% to the Nvidia chipset which will be a larger battery drain.

The issue, according to those users, is that the integrated graphics on the Retina MBP is the root cause and more than likely to be as a result of immature drivers from Intel since they also report that there is no issue under Bootcamp.